# Sharepooint Color Progress Bar Calculated column not working in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, calculated-column

I copied a formula for color coded progress bar from Path to sharepoint [site](https://pathtosharepoint.wordpress.com/2008/10/21/progress-bar-color-coding/) 
And everything seems simple, however I think this code was written for sharepoint 2013 and I am getting error for sharepoint 2013. Seems like code is correct however maybe not supported in 2013.

Do you know any workaround? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
="<DIV style='position:relative;'><DIV style='background-color:"&CHOOSE(INT(&#91;%&#93;*10)+1,"red","red","OrangeRed","OrangeRed","DarkOrange","Orange","Gold","yellow","GreenYellow","LawnGreen","Lime")&"; width:"&(&#91;%&#93;*100)&"%;'>&nbsp;</DIV><DIV style='position:absolute; top:0px;'>"&TEXT([% Complete],"0%")&"</DIV></DIV>"
```

Thanks
KD

Comment: What is the exact requirement and conditions for this column? Can you explain more?